# Node.js and Electron ABI Version

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-rebuild

I am trying to use `libxmljs2` for use on both (1) a simple node.js application and (2) an Electron application.

So the versions I am using are the following:

```
Electron: 11.2.0 (ABI version 85)
Node.js: 12.20.1 (ABI version 72)
```

So my problem is.. since I am using a shared node_module (this is our architecture so I can't deviate from it) for the node.js app and electron app:

- when I rebuild `libxmljs2` with `npm rebuild` - it works well for node.js but not for the electron app
- when I rebuild with `electron-rebuild --module-dir libxmljs2` then it works for the electron app but not for node.js

So I say shared node_modules as this:

```
developmentFolder
|_ node_modules
|_ node-app
|_ electron-app
```

`node-app` and `electron-app` share with `node_modules`. Both `node-app` and `electron-app` do not have their own node_modules folder inside.

Help anyone?

Comment: it's unfortunate, but you cannot share same binary between two different abi incompatible runtime. 1. rebuild each time as you mentioned 2. split module location to have separate binary 3. upstream supports n-api works on different abi is only way.